# PHP MongoDate/DateTime bug or missunderstanding

Tags: php, datetime, mongodate

Is there something wrong with the MongoDate feature?

When I convert a DateTime Object to MongoDate, and then I try to convert it back to DateTime, I get a totally different value. Keep in mind we're talking about a date within the EPOCH limits.

Here's a way to reproduce the issue.

```
$dateTime  = new DateTime( '2015-07-20 10:15:45', new DateTimeZone( 'Europe/London' ) );

$mongoDate = new MongoDate( $dateTime->getTimeStamp() );

echo $mongoDate->sec ."\n"; // 1437383745

echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $mongoDate->sec ) ."\n"; // 2015-07-20 11:15:45

$dateTime2 = $mongoDate->toDateTime();

echo $dateTime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ."\n"; // 1969-12-15 10:41:40
```

Is this behaviour normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have timezone issue. When you create DateTime object, you create it in `Europe/London` timezone. But when you "convert" seconds back to datetime format, you use `date()` function, which uses default timezone, which apparently is different from `Europe/London`.

Create DateTime object with `$mongoDate->sec` and then convert timezone.

```php
$dt = new DateTime('@' . $mongoDate->sec);
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $dt->format('c');
```